# GoogleMaps view in a tab

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am working with the basic android studio tabs example. I was wondering if on each tab can you have a separate activity? Or is that what fragments are used for. I have a separate simple google maps application (activity) that I am trying to integrate into the tabs example. I was wondering if in this part of the tabbed example where is sets up the corresponding fragment if I could put the intent to the maps activity there?

```
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this is the basic maps activity

```
public class MapsView extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_view);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

and the corresponding fragment for the map view

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsView" />
```

I guess if I am not making any sense I really just want some guidance on the best way to incorporate the maps into a tabbed view.

Comment: The old school way (pre-3.0) would be 1 activity per tab.  These days its generally done via fragments instead.

Comment: So how would I use that fragment to pop it in one of the tabs, if u dont mind?

Answer (score 0):

This will teach you everything you need to know:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

To sum it up, you return a new fragment instance inside of an FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem() method. Such fragment should contain your MapView. This way, you can load different fragments (with different layouts) at will.

A word of caution though: last time I tried using a MapView this way, it simply did not load (only a blank grid). I am positive it had nothing to do with my key, since using a MapFragment (a different approach) turned out alright.